# Notice: Undefined index: variable

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to build the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="Index.php">
  <label>Name </label>
  <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here"><br />
  </br>
  <label>Email </label>
  <input name="email" placeholder="Type Here">
  <br /></br>
  <label style="display:block;">I need some information regarding:</label>
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
  <br />
  <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
  <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
  <br />
  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="height:30px;">
</form>
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $from = 'From: TangledDemo';
  $to = 'hello@emailaddress.com';
  $subject = 'Hello';
  $human = $_POST['human'];

  $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

  if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
      echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else {
      echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
    }
  } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
  }

  if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
      if ($human == '4') {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
          echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else {
          echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
        }
      } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
      }
    } else {
      echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
    }
  }
?>
```

But constantly getting these errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\bet4info\Index.php on
>   line 19
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\bet4info\Index.php
>   on line 20
>
> Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\bet4info\Index.php
>   on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined index: human in C:\xampp\htdocs\bet4info\Index.php
>   on line 25
>
> Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\bet4info\Index.php
>   on line 29
>
> Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\bet4info\Index.php
>   on line 35
>
> Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\bet4info\Index.php
>   on line 38

Why is it so?

Comment: Because you set as example name from a $_POST and do not use the isset function before check is value

Comment: This is working for me, but you need to apply `isset()` on `$_POST` values.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Wrong. And that because? You need to use isset on each var you think can be not initilized, such as php suggest, not necessarily on $_POST but as example only on $name (in OP case)

Comment: If your given code is in a single file, you will definitely get those errors.

Comment: i said $_POST values, means each value he need to check. just read my comment completly.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh to explain a little more, is it correct to check $_post value (if exist) before setting variables, but you need to use isset on each var (generic) that can be not existent before using it, otherwise you'll get an error and not a notice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {
```

use

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $human == '4') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Into this, first you have to check using the `isset` function:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) &&....)
{
    // If isset then assign data to variable $name = $_POST['name'],...
}
else
{
    // Redirect to the error page
}
```

As like this, the same for all the variables.